# Finding values between symbols by regex where symbol might be part of value

Tags: python, regex

There is a string which I am trying to extract values from between symbols, but the symbol or delimiter also happens to be part of the string.

Assume the string below:

```
message =': :1:1st message:2a:2nd message:x:this is where it fails status: fail :3:3rd message'
```

and the desired results:

```
['1st message','2nd message','this is where it fails status: fail','3rd message']
```

Current code and results:

```
import re
def trans(text):
    text = text+':'
    tag = re.findall(r':(.*?):',text)
    return [i for i in tag if not i.isspace()]

trans(message)

>>['1st message', '2nd message', 'this is where it fails status', '3']
```

Any idea how I can form my regex to also include the pattern to include `'status: fail '` as part of the results?

Comment: Hey tried that to, does not work, in my case I am using findall from re.

Comment: Have you thought of splitting using [(?::\s*(?=:))?:\[a-zA-Z0-9\]+:](https://regex101.com/r/7Oo6K8/1) ? And it works perfectly fine, whats the problem ?? If you want to do things the hard way, use findall with a regex that has two capture groups and stop trying to match _just your designer text_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `r'[^\s]:(.*?):(?!\s)`.

Result:

> ```
> ['1st message',
>  '2nd message',
>  'this is where it fails status: fail ',
>  '3rd message']
> ```

- `[^\s]` is to not match a colon which is preceded by a whitespace character so it fixes `3rd message`.
- `:(?!\s)` is to match a **colon not followed by a whitespace character** so it fixes `status: fail`.
- in other words, both pieces I have added create a margin around the substring being matched which must not consist of a colon preceded or followed by a whitespace character.

Comment: Hey, I am not getting 3rd message. Just FYI, the between colon separators might be a few characters and contain alphanumeric. EDIT: sorry mixed up, did not know you were using the function to append ':', it works now!

Comment: @BernardL That's weird, that result is an output of the script as you posted in your question. I have just changed the regexp.

Comment: Edited my comment. Thanks for the solution! Just so I understand better, the regex you posted in looking forward for seperators between colons and look aheads?

Comment: @BernardL It simply matches any string (including colons followed by a whitespace character) until a colon followed by a non-whitespace character is reached. Is it understandable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
re.findall(r'(?<=:\S:).+?(?=\s*:.:|$)', message)
```

Lookbehind for a character inside colons (or the beginning of the string), then match and lazy-repeat any character until lookahead sees another character inside colons (or the end of the string).

Output:

```
['1st message', '2nd message', 'this is where it fails status: fail', '3rd message']
```

Comment: Hey sorry, I forgot to add that the inside colons might be alphanumeric, I just edited by post. It works well without alphanumeric though. It takes me some time to read regex, sorry.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, here the assumption is that the number of alphanumeric characters between 2 `:` s is always 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `:\d+:\K.*?(?=:\d+|$)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lTSqSp/1)

Comment: The `re` module does not support `\K`, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, but sadly I only have python available for me. I also understand that you used \d to define numbers in between to be separators but in my case, it could be alphanumeric. Thanks.

Comment: @BernardL, is the no. of alpha numeric characters between the separators fixed (here 1 char)?

Comment: @Matt.G sadly no, I marked an answer above that works well though.